# how to create round content slider?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slider

Who knows how to create such slider? May be there is some plugins, Google search has not suggested anything..

[image]

By clicking on the arrows or on the icons themselves - slider to spin, clicked icon appears at the top, and accordingly changes the content in the red box.

Comment: Please review [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) questions on Stack Overflow and what types of questions [**can be asked**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and what types [**should be avoided.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to do something like this is to use transform:rotateZ as shown in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gb090786/2/)

**updated to automate a lot of steps**

The way it works is it defines a 'dial', and rotates 'div.item's inside the dial so they space out equally around the dial. It then rotates '.icon's inside each div so they appear straight.

```
<div id='dial'>
    <div id='item1'class='item'>
        <div class='icon'>1</div>
    </div>
    <div id='item2' class='item'>
        <div class='icon'>2</div>
    </div>
    ... 
</div>
```

It get's turned into a proper looking dial by applying the following css.

```
#dial{
    width:500px;
    height:500px;
    border-radius:100%;
    border:1px solid black;
    position:relative;
}
.item{
    position:absolute;
    left:225px;
    top:10px;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    border:1px solid gray;
    border-radius:100%;
    text-align:center;
    transform-origin:25px 225px;
}
.icon{
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    transform-origin:25px 25px;
}
```

important is to define the transform origin of the items, so they rotate around the center of the dial instead of their own center. The actual rotation of each individual item and div is performed by the script. The script also automatically attaches handlers for rotating the dial left and right, and to jump to items.

```
function dial(el){
    var $dial = $(el);
    var $items = $dial.find('.item');
    var amount = $items.length;
    var degStep = 360/amount;
    var startAngle = 0;

    this.rotateItems = function(){
        $items.each(function(i){
            var d = i*degStep+startAngle;
            $(this).css({transform:'rotateZ('+d+'deg)'})
            .find('.icon').css({transform:'rotateZ('+(-d)+'deg)'});
        });
    };

    this.rotateLeft = function(){
        startAngle -= degStep;
        this.rotateItems();
    }

    this.rotateRight = function(){
        startAngle += degStep;
        this.rotateItems();
    }

    this.jumpTo = function(a){
        startAngle = a;
        this.rotateItems();
    }
    this.init = function(){
        var that = this;
        this.rotateItems();
        $dial.find('.left').click(function(){
            that.rotateLeft();
        });
        $dial.find('.right').click(function(){
            that.rotateRight();
        });
        $items.each(function(i){
            var d = i*degStep;
            $(this).click(function(){
                that.jumpTo(-d);
            });
        });
        return this;
    }

};
```

**Edited** with your request for active Icon and icon-dependant content. When we rotate the wheel, we now determine active index like so:

```
 activeI = -startAngle/degStep%amount;
 if (activeI<0){activeI+=amount;}
```

*it's probably just as easy or easier to keep track of the active index directly, but this works just fine*

In our rotateItems loop we then check if the item has this index, and if it does, we make it active and we update the content

```
 if (i==activeI){
     $(this).addClass('activeItem');
     $dial.find('.content').text($(this).data('text')).css({backgroundColor:$(this).data('css')});
```

There's tons of ways to get content from the active item, either you use data attributes, like i did, or you add hidden divs with content that you copy, or you do ajax queries based on item index, or use javascript arrays.. Tons of way to do it, really depends on what kind of content you want to display.

A method that uses hidden divs inside items with content can be found [here](https://jsfiddle.net/gb090786/3/)

So items are defined as such

```
<div data-css='red' class='item'>
    <div class='icon'>1</div>
    <div class='dial-content'>
        <h1>this is a header 1</h1>
        <p>and here is more content</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

with .dial-content not being displayed by using css

```
.dial-content{
    display:none;
}
```

html gets copied from the active item by use of

```
 $dial.find('.content')
     .html($(this).find('.dial-content').html())
     .css({backgroundColor:$(this).data('css')});
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. But can I put there content in center, and bind it to each `.item` ? And also I need to add some class for `.item` on the top, for change icon color and background.

Comment: @CroaToa updated with item dependant content

Comment: You almost saved me, thank you so much. Data-text probably not suitable for me, because I want to add there not only text but also html markup. Finally, if you prompt how to add there html markup I'll accept your answer. Once again, thank you very much.

Comment: @CroaToa you can have html markup in the data-text no problem, just that you will need to use .html($(this).data('text')) instead of .text(..) but i'll update the fiddle with another option if needed

Comment: @CroaToa added another fiddle (last line) that uses hidden divs with content inside, that get loaded when the item becomes active (note that i only added content to 1 2 and 8)

Comment: That is what I want! Thank you! Bounty yours after 2 hours

Answer (score 3):

I like [Pie Menu Generator](http://pmg.softwaretailoring.net/) (PMG). It's based on [wheelnav.js](http://wheelnavjs.softwaretailoring.net/), and enables you to create an SVG spinning wheel menu by choosing from the available options, and seeing the results in a demo.

The main downside to this module is it's dependency on [raphael.js](http://raphaeljs.com/), which is a slight overkill when you just need it for the menu.

Change `changeContent(item)` to display your content.

Working Demo:

```js
var piemenu = new wheelnav('piemenu');
piemenu.sliceInitPathFunction = piemenu.slicePathFunction;
piemenu.initPercent = 0.1;
piemenu.wheelRadius = piemenu.wheelRadius * 0.83;
piemenu.createWheel();

var contentArea = document.getElementById('piemenuContent');

changeContent(0);

function changeContent(item) {

    var index = typeof item === 'number' ? item : item.wheelItemIndex;

    switch(index) {
        case 0:
            contentArea.innerHTML = '<img src="http://s.hswstatic.com/gif/singapura-cat.jpg" class="pieContent">';
        break;

        case 1:
            contentArea.innerHTML = '<iframe src="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pie_menu" class="pieContent"></iframe>';
        break;

        case 2:
            contentArea.innerHTML = '<video class="pieContent" autoplay><source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4"><source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.ogg" type="video/ogg">Your browser does not support HTML5 video.</video>';
        break;
    }
}
```

```css
#piemenuWrapper { position: relative; width: 100vmax; height: 100vmax; }
#piemenuContent { position: absolute; top: 220px; right: 220px; bottom: 220px; left: 220px; overflow: hidden; }
.pieContent { width: 100%; height: 100%; }
#piemenu > svg { width: 100%; height: 100%; }
#piemenu { height: 100%; width: 100%; margin:auto; }
@media (max-width: 400px) { #piemenu { height: 300px; width: 300px; } }

[class|=wheelnav-piemenu-slice-basic] { fill: #497F4C; stroke: none; }
[class|=wheelnav-piemenu-slice-selected] { fill: #497F4C; stroke: none; }
[class|=wheelnav-piemenu-slice-hover] { fill: #497F4C;  stroke: none; fill-opacity: 0.77; cursor: pointer; }

[class|=wheelnav-piemenu-title-basic] { fill: #333; stroke: none; }
[class|=wheelnav-piemenu-title-selected] { fill: #fff; stroke: none; }
[class|=wheelnav-piemenu-title-hover] { fill: #222; stroke: none; cursor: pointer; }
[class|=wheelnav-piemenu-title] > tspan { font-family: Impact, Charcoal, sans-serif; font-size: 24px; }
```

```html
<script src="http://wheelnavjs.softwaretailoring.net/js/raphael.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://wheelnavjs.softwaretailoring.net/js/raphael.icons.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://wheelnavjs.softwaretailoring.net/js/wheelnav.min.js"></script>
<div id='piemenuWrapper'>
<div id='piemenuContent'>
</div>
<div id='piemenu' data-wheelnav
 data-wheelnav-slicepath='DonutSlice'
 data-wheelnav-navangle='270'
 data-wheelnav-cssmode 
 data-wheelnav-init>
  <div data-wheelnav-navitemtext='0' onmouseup='changeContent(this);'></div>
  <div data-wheelnav-navitemtext='1' onmouseup='changeContent(this);'></div>
  <div data-wheelnav-navitemtext='2' onmouseup='changeContent(this);'></div>
  <div data-wheelnav-navitemtext='3' onmouseup='changeContent(this);'></div>
  <div data-wheelnav-navitemtext='4' onmouseup='changeContent(this);'></div>
  <div data-wheelnav-navitemtext='5' onmouseup='changeContent(this);'></div>
  <div data-wheelnav-navitemtext='6' onmouseup='changeContent(this);'></div>
  <div data-wheelnav-navitemtext='7' onmouseup='changeContent(this);'></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. Unfortunately I need this for content slider, not for menu. I need change content in center depending on which icon top.